# how to check if class is between 50 and 150 pixels from top and then select classes id attribute

Tags: jquery

Im trying to find a cleaner way of detecting whether a class is towards the top of the screen - but within a certain threshold. For example between 50 and 150 pixels from top.

i've done something here that uses the ID to check, but it's very repetitive.  is it possible to get a class working with this instead of ID?

```
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var elementFromTop = $('#section_a').offset().top;          
     var distanceFromTop  = (elementFromTop - scrollTop);
     if (distanceFromTop > 0 && distanceFromTop < 100) {
       console.log("section_a in zone- highlight link in nav");
     }
   });

   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var elementFromTop = $('#section_b').offset().top;          
     var distanceFromTop  = (elementFromTop - scrollTop);
     if (distanceFromTop > 0 && distanceFromTop < 100) {
       console.log("section_b in zone- highlight link in nav");
     }
   });

   <div class="section" id="section_a"> width is 100%</div>
   <div class="section" id="section_b"> width is 100%</div>
```

Comment: Ya, it is possible. So what have you tried? BTW, look at waypoints plugin if you need more robust solution

Comment: someone had suggested i loop through all the classes.  what ended up happening was nothing would trigger because (i assume) there are moments where 2 classes appears on page at the same time.    unfortunately i dont have that code test anymore.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that sounds unlikely. Can you put up a JS fiddle?  And to be sure, you are calling your jquery from inside a document ready section.   E.g.  $(function(){ /*codehere*/ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try applying that code using jquery's .each().

Something like this?

```
$('.myclass').each(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var elementFromTop = $('#' + id ).offset().top;          
     var distanceFromTop  = (elementFromTop - scrollTop);
     if (distanceFromTop > 0 && distanceFromTop < 100) {
       console.log("id" + id + " in zone- highlight link in nav");
     }
});
```

This will apply your code to each item of that class.

Comment: just remember to replace '#section_a' with this var elementFromTop = $(this).offset().top;

Comment: it worked!  thank you so much.  i did find a flaw in my logic though.  if the screen is large, sometimes a class will never fall into the top area of the page.  next step is to figure out how to check if it's in the middle of the page.

it says i dont have enough rep to upvote you :/

Comment: ah, i think var elementFromTop = $('#' + id ).offset().top - 300; 
if (distanceFromTop > 0 && distanceFromTop < 500) {   ....  sort of fixes the middle of page issue.  testing further.

Comment: Nice one :)   Shout if you get stuck, but my time at the pc is kind of erratic at this time of year.